# AngularJS - Display Banner after 2 rows, followed by another 2 Rows

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to display a Banner `<div>` after 2 rows of 4 x `"col-md-3"`, followed by another 2 Rows - so the resulting markup would look like:

```
 <div class="col-md-3">1</div>
 <div class="col-md-3">2</div>
 <div class="col-md-3">3</div>
 <div class="col-md-3">4</div>
 <div class="col-md-3">5</div>
 <div class="col-md-3">6</div>
 <div class="col-md-3">7</div>
 <div class="col-md-3">8</div>
 <div class="col-md-12" id="Banner">Banner</div>
 <div class="col-md-3">9</div>
 <div class="col-md-3">10</div>
 <div class="col-md-3">11</div>
 <div class="col-md-3">12</div>
 <div class="col-md-3">13</div>
 <div class="col-md-3">14</div>
 <div class="col-md-3">15</div>
 <div class="col-md-3">16</div>
```

Trying to simulate this using AngularJS so would have to use `ng-repeat` - but cannot seem to get this working. Any help appreciated: [My Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/k429fg00Yf9KPJswlxjS?p=preview)

```
  <div ng-repeat="n in Numbers">
    <div class="col-md-3">{{n}}</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are just a couple of problems with your plunker. First maincontroller.js is missing the .js extension, so it is never loaded.

Next all of the references to load angular should start with https instead of just http.

To display the banner after a certain number of rows place it within the first div and use something like:

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="Banner" ng-if="$index==5">Banner</div>
```

Not sure if 5 is the number you want there or if you want to use some kind of expression to see if ng-if is divisible by a certain value, but using $index and ng-if should get you there.

Comment: Thanks for that - but how could I get the Banner <div> to display after the first 2 rows?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-include` with a `ng-if` to conditionally include the banner if it's at the correct index with `n===8`.

Please have a look at the code below or in this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/sV6DZcRzXNQGQjYSOIFp?p=preview).

```js
 angular.module("app", [])
        .controller("MainController", mainController);

function mainController($scope) {

        $scope.Numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainController" ng-app="app">
    
      <h1>Demo</h1>
      
      <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat-start="n in Numbers">{{n}}</div>
      <div ng-include="'banner.html'" ng-if="(n === 8)" ng-repeat-end></div>
      
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="banner.html">
      <div class="col-md-12" id="Banner">Banner</div>
      </script>
  
    </div>
```